# How to support both json and jsonp responses in node.js + Express?

Tags: json, node.js, rest, express, jsonp

I'm have a REST API service, written on Node.js + Express, which currently support responses in JSON format.

Now, I need to add support for JSONP responses too, so everyone may get it by adding *alt=JSONP* to the request string.

So, my question is, which is the best way to do so?

Possible, there is an pattern, or living example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The officially supported method is as follows --

First, set your JSONP callback parameter name:

`app.set('jsonp callback name', 'callback');`

Then, change all instances of `res.json` or `res.send` to `res.jsonp`.
For example, `res.jsonp(500, { error: 'message' })`

If the `callback` parameter is supplied in a request, the response will be wrapped as JSONP using the supplied function name, but if it isn't, it'll just return JSON.

Afterwards, this returns JSONP:
GET /myapi/v1/users?callback=responseCallback

This does not:
GET /myapi/v1/users

Reference http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.jsonp

Comment: But how about POST or DELETE requests? As far as I know, it will not working for JSONP.

Comment: It should work exactly the same way. As far as express is concerned, GET/POST/DELETE/etc are all the same thing, they just dispatch differently.

As far as *making* those requests, you'll have to use method override. https://github.com/expressjs/method-override

Comment: great answer! I got crazy looking for it.

Comment: Obviously there are no post or delete requests in jsonp.